# IPython Notebooks Unreadable

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

So I just installed IPython for the first time (Windows 7 64 bit).  Followed the instructions here:

[IPython Installation](http://ipython.org/install.html#)

Downloaded and installed Anaconda 1.9.1 then gave the commands

```
conda update conda
conda update ipython
```

(running the command line terminal as an Administrator)

Installation completed OK and I tried to open an example .ipynb notebook file from here;

[Example IPython Notebook File](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/url/github.com/ipython/ipython/raw/master/examples/notebooks/Part%201%20-%20Running%20Code.ipynb)

but I get the following error;

```
Error loading notebook
Unreadable Notebook: Notebook does not appear to be JSON: '\n\n
```

I've tried a number of other example notebooks from the [IPython Example Notebooks](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/examples/notebooks#a-collection-of-notebooks-for-using-ipython-effectively) and all fail to open and give the same error!

Anybody know what is wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: Does `conda update ipython-notebook` help?

Comment: @PaulH `conda update ipython-notebook` UN-linked ipython-1.2.1 and linked ipython-1.1.0 but sadly did not make a difference to the error on opening the notebook.

Comment: other question: are you sure you just saved the notebook JSON and not the webpage?

Comment: @PaulH Visited [IPython Examples](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/examples/notebooks#a-collection-of-notebooks-for-using-ipython-effectively) Using Chrome, right click on the notebook of interest, click 'Save link as...' and the .ipynb file appears in the IPython Notebook folder.  Think I'm doing it right?

Comment: Your links are broken

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Based on the comment:

> Visited IPython Examples Using Chrome, right click on the notebook of interest, 
>   click 'Save link as...' and the .ipynb file appears in
>   the IPython Notebook folder. Think I'm doing it right?

It's clear that you're downloading the whole webpage, not the notebooks. Following that procedure and opening the resulting file in a text editor, I get something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <meta name="description" content="">



    <meta name="author" content="">


    <!--NEW RELIC Start Perf Measurement-->

    <!--NREND-->

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <!--<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    ...
```

What you need to do is follow each link to [it's nbviewer rendering](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Part%201%20-%20Running%20Code.ipynb), and click the download link.

[image]

Alternatively, I would just download or clone the repository from github, change to the resulting directory, and start the notebook server there.

Comment: Thanks for that; clicking on the Download Notebook button on the nbviewer rendering brings up a page of code.  In order to download the notebook file itself I needed to right click the Download Notebook button and then 'Save as...'  Then I finally had the IPython notebook file in the correct format and was able to open it. Not exactly intuitive for a first time user, but I got there in the end.